# why does arm atomic_[read/write] operations implemented as volatile pointers?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, arm64, atomic, memory-barriers

He is example of atomic_read implementation:

```
#define atomic_read(v) (*(volatile int *)&(v)->counter)
```

Also, should we explicitly use memory barriers for atomic operations on arm?

Comment: Obviously to prevent compiler time optimization based on assumtions that value won't change.

Comment: the atomic operations applies to memory cell, if the value will be cached in a register this will make no sense. Regarding barriers - in general, no, but in particular context this might be needed.

Comment: volatile indicates the compiler not to optimize read and writes. The expression also force address generation (so it force the thing to be in memory, so no `register`). Note `volatile sig_atomic_t` is in standard C, and so it has also some meaning for all compilers (unlike `register` that can be ignored).

Comment: The definition above does not use the atomic builtins of GCC. I also think it is confusing to call it atomic_read(). Compiling that does not automatically add any barriers. Perhaps the question should be why that is fine, since it is how the kernel implements it.

Comment: This document explains it: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/atomic_t.txt

There must be an `atomic_read_acquire()` and `atomic_set_release()` defined, which provide memory ordering.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi The volatile qualifier has a std meaning for all types, not just for `volatile sig_atomic_t`. It means that the operations should only assume ABI conventions on the object and nothing else.

Comment: @curiousguy: not really, volatile requires that values are not cached between read (and writes). K&R had an example about it (IIRC about reading clock). But std C has some extra requirements (alignments, etc.), and the environment part (of std C) has some assumptions, so compilers could use the "as if" principle to optimize anyway. This question is about kernel, "free standing environment" (IIRC from std C), which broke many assumptions. Linus Torvalds often complained about gcc breaking kernel by overoptimizing (gcc following std C) and making assumption that in kernel were not true.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi 1) Values should be read and written in memory how exactly? "_and the environment part (of std C) has some assumptions_" Which assumptions? Do you agree that the compiler will read and write objects with type `volatile T` strictly according to the ABI for type `T`? 2) Strictly applying the std and assuming code is strictly conforming will break many programs not specially the kernel. A lot of code assumes that code using `int` can count on the CPU integer addition behavior, that is, on a CPU with 2-compl and modulo overflow, you get that behavior in C/C++. You don't with GCC.

Comment: 3) But if you only use `volatile int` objects, you get that underlying behavior. Now **I warn you that if you post an answer saying that on SO, it will be deleted.**

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi AFAIK the areas were the kernel code conflicts w/ optimizations are: 1) inline `asm` (allegedly missing dependencies, but the specification was not historically so clear) 2) predictable int overflow 3) reading data w/ a larger type (fast copy) 4) manipulating data w/ a struct type (zero copy in incoming data) 5) using a cast to volatile to have atomic semantics -> **all of which** are programming methods equally applicable in application code.

Comment: @curiousguy: as you see, comments are not useful for discussion (too short). 1- Every time code need a volatile variable, that should be read from memory (usually it could be cached in a registry. Volatile mean that the value could be changed externally.). 2- I mean an other thing: std C compilers can optimize code if they predict it would not change the behaviour (by following some requirements of C std which are NOT valid in kernel). The main problem is about gcc moving part of code in different locations (outside barriers), or thinking *0 is "NULL" so undeferentiable or tricks on `return`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He is example of atomic_read implementation:

A problematic one actually, which assumes that a cast is not a nop, *which isn't guaranteed*.

> Also, should we explicitly use memory barriers for atomic operations
>   on arm?

Probably. It depends on what you are doing and what you are *expecting*.

Comment: The code is from an earlier Linux ARM kernel were it is mandated to use GCC.  The above answer is correct that this is generically wrong, but the OP has posted with little context and there is nothing wrong with the macro **IF** you are using GCC (which honours the cast) and you are not on an SMP system (no need for barriers).  More recent kernels (say 2014+) have been update to address these issues. See: [LKML 2014](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1410.0/01389.html)  The change was for all arches, not just ARM.  Also, barriers aren't **IF** you know it is accessed by a single CPU.

Comment: @artlessnoise "_there is nothing wrong with the macro IF you are using GCC_" What is your source on that one?

Comment: The versions of gcc are pegged by the header files when you compile the kernel; if not, it throws an error and the approved GCC versions (when this was active) was treating volatile as a reload.

Comment: @artlessnoise Does any GCC version promises to **treat the result of cast to volatile as referring to a volatile obj?** Or it is an happy accident?

Comment: `counter` itself is an atomic_t; it can be cached after a read.  The important part is to read the entire value and not just a part of it and to do it at the sequence point.  I think the accepted answer is wrong and was only adding a comment that your answer was more correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the casting to volatile is to prevent the compiler from assuming the value of v cannot change.  As for using memory barriers, the GCC builtins already allow you to specify the memory ordering you desire, no need to do it manually: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html#g_t_005f_005fatomic-Builtins

The default behavior on GCC is to use `__ATOMIC_SEQ_CST` which will emit the barriers necessary on Arm to make sure your atomics execute in the order you place them in the code.  To optimize performance on Arm, you will want to consider using weaker semantics to allow the compiler to elide barriers and let the hardware execute faster.  For more information on the types of memory barriers the Arm architecture has, see https://developer.arm.com/docs/den0024/latest/memory-ordering/barriers.